# Google Maps API - Custom Markers

Tags: ios, api, maps

Is it possible to have specific markers based on a user's search with Google Maps API? For example, I'd like to be able to create unique markers for different food cuisine types: american, asian, european, and indian. If the user types in `american` for example, can I add a special marker for this and if so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has a great API that details how to do what you need pretty well. The [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests) has some examples of how to search for places. The [Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex) has an example on how to add custom marker symbols. Once you get the data back from the query posted, you can parse it to get details on the restaurant and associate an icon with that restaurants position

Comment: Thank you for your response! Do you by chance have a resource you use for parsing? I'm unsure what that entails -- getting information from the restaurant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the iOS SDK (I just looked at your tags):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker